# Prove $\langle v,v\rangle=\langle w,w\rangle $ implies $v=w$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

This may seem rather simple, but I'm trying to rigorously confirm this intuition. Can anyone help?

Suppose v,w are elements of V. Prove:  $\langle v,v\rangle=\langle w,w\rangle\ \implies v=w$.

Comment: What you probably mean is if $\langle v,w\rangle=\langle w,w\rangle$, but unfortunately your intuition is wrong (unless I misinterpreted). It only implies that $v-w$ is orthogonal to $w$.

Comment: If you really mean what you wrote, that's even less correct. The entire unit sphere consists of the vectors $v$ with $\langle v,v\rangle=1$.

Comment: It's very sad that this was closed as off topic, but it really confirms that people are grossly misusing their closing power.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even when $V$ is one-dimensional: $$\langle -1,-1\rangle=\langle 1,1\rangle$$ but $1\ne-1$.

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align}
\langle v, v \rangle &= \langle w, w \rangle \iff \\
\lVert v \rVert &= \lVert w \rVert
\end{align}
so the vectors still can have different directions, if they have non-zero length.